# date() inside class causes an error

Tags: php, class

This is no doubt a super dumb question, im getting to grips with classes and im trying to assign a variable, if i use a string as the variable value it works fine but when i use:

```
class MyTest{
    private $my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}

$my_test = new MyTest;
echo $my_test->$my_date;
```

Then i get a server error but it doesnt print any log saying whats wrong, dreamviewer shows it as an error too but if i load it outside of the class its fine.

No laughing please, what am i doing wrong?

if i do this

```
class MyTest{
    private $my_date = "today";
}

$my_test = new MyTest;
echo $my_test->$my_date;
```

Then i get no error.

Comment: You got your answer (use `__construct`), also, it should be `$my_test = new MyTest();` with parenthesis

Comment: Also, the echo must have generated a fatal error since you are trying to access a private property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call functions when declaring class variables. You need to set the value inside your class constructor. Like this:

```
class MyTest{
    private $my_date;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}
```

See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Class member declaration "may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated."

Comment: cheers, i just noticed it worked inside the function but i still couldnt make it private or public so i see now i declare it outside and set it inside, thanks i have it now, appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Calling functions while declaration like you do isn't possible. Do it like this:

```
class MyTest{
    public $my_date;

    function __construct() {
        $this->my_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }
}

$my_test = new MyTest;
echo $my_test->my_date;
```

Apart from this, you have to make the variable public if you want to call it from outside the class. And calling variables is done without $ after the ->.